# Can I return multi values from one form to another

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I have 2 forms,the first form4 which is a dataGridView contains informartions from the database,when I clic on "New" button,The form5 is showing a formular that I should fill then clic on the "add" button,finally,the result I get should appear in the datagridView of Form4.
is that possible?
this is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("insert into journal values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','" + checkBox1.Checked.ToString()+"','"+checkBox2.Checked.ToString()+"');", connection);
    int o = sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show(o + " Le Fichier journal a ?t? ajout? avec succ?s");
    connection.Close();
    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox2.Text = "";
    if(textBox1.Text ==" ")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("La saisie du code Journal est obligatoire!!");
    }
    affich();             
}
 
private void affich()
{
    try
    {
        pat = connectionString;
        req = "SELECT * FROM journal";
        con = new SqlConnection(pat);
        con.Open();
        dr = new SqlDataAdapter(req, con);
        dr.Fill(ds, "journal");
        Form4 Form4 = new Form4();//ceci va creer une nouvelle instance je ne veux pas avoir une nouvelleFen?te
        Form4.journalDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables["journal"];
        Form4.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show("Base de donn?es non trouv?e", e.Message); }
}
```

and the 2 forms:
[image]

thanks for Help

Comment: It becomes a very simple/trivial solution if you have an object to contain your data

Comment: Sir can you explain more I'am just a biginner in C# and thanks :)

Comment: One possible solution for you would be to add an event on your Form4, smth like `OnEntryAdded()` and add a refresh method on your main form as the handler for that event.

Comment: If you have an object that contains all the data then you just pass that object back to your first form, then it should contain all data you wish to include into your grid. On top of this, `DataGridView`'s are capable of auto generating the columns for objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Requirement**: A button in `Form5` should add results in the `DataGridView` present in `Form4` without creating new instance of `Form4`

In `Form4` change the `Modifiers` property of `journalDataGridView` as `Public`.

Following changes required:

```
public partial class Form5 : Form
{ 
    Form4 form4;

    public Form5(Form4 f4)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form4 = f4;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        ...
        ...
        affich();
    }

    private void affich()
    {
       try
       {
           pat = connectionString;
           req = "SELECT * FROM journal";
           con = new SqlConnection(pat);
           con.Open();
           dr = new SqlDataAdapter(req, con);
           dr.Fill(ds, "journal");
           form4.journalDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables["journal"];
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           MessageBox.Show("Base de donn?es non trouv?e", e.Message); 
       }
    }   
}
```

How to Create  `Form5` instance from `Form4`:

Inside Form4.cs:

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public Form4()
    {
       InitializeComponent();       
    }

    private void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         Form5 form5 = new Form5(this);
         form5.Show();
    }
    ...
 }
```

Or From any other parent form:

```
//must have valid Form4 objForm4
Form5 form5 = new Form5(objForm4);
```

Comment: It is possible to name a variable the same way as a class. It is not something that anyone should even do of course though.

Comment: For that you have to pass same instance of `form4` to `form5`.

Answer (score 3):

please try this code method :

```
private void affich()
        {
            try
            {
                pat = connectionString;
                req = "SELECT * FROM journal";
                con = new SqlConnection(pat);
                con.Open();
                dr = new SqlDataAdapter(req, con);
                dr.Fill(ds, "journal");
                Form4 obj= new Form4();//ceci va creer une nouvelle instance je ne veux pas avoir une nouvelleFenête
                obj.journalDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables["journal"];
                Form4.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show("Base de données non trouvée", e.Message); }
        }
```

Comment: thanks @vishu minhas for your code,when I apply it it will create a new instance of Form4 with the new data just added but what I want that the result of add appear in the dataGridView of Form4 (not creating a new form) :)

Comment: `Form4.Show()` should be `obj.Show()`